# convert cells in to an array of variant

Tags: excel, vba

I need to store some cell values into an array of variants. (I'm using this array in a for each loop, so it has to be variant) The following code gives a type mismatch error. Could someone please show me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub MainSub()
    Dim ws_names() As Variant
    ws_names = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("K3:K5")
    ShowCertainWorksheets ws_names
End Sub

Public Sub ShowCertainWorksheets(ByVal ws_names As Variant)
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = True
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

Worksheets("Lookup").Range("K3:K5") contains only worksheet names that exist in the file so there's no problem there...

Comment: please show the code for `ShowCertainWorksheets`.  Also try adding `.Value` to the end of `ws_names = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("K3:K5")`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error somewhere? What are the expected results? What results are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive enough. It gives a typemistch error on the line ws_names = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("K3:K5").

Comment: Worksheet.Range returns a `Variant`, not a `Variant()`.  If there is more than one cell, it will be sub-typed as an array.

Comment: @GarryWang as I stated in my first comment: Put `.Value` at the end: `ws_names = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("K3:K5").Value`

Comment: Or do what @Comintern stated and remove the `()` from the declaration: `Dim ws_names As Variant`  Either will get you the answer to your question.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! That's really helpful.